# How do I get the value in event hander function (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, bind

I want to get the value in the event hander function.
If clicks prints in event hander function, then it will show 1, 2, 3, 4... by every click.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
clicks = 0

def click(event):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    print(clicks)

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me!")
button.pack()
button.bind("<Button-1>", click)

root.mainloop()
```

If I print it in global, it will show 0 forever. But I want it prints 1, 2, 3 by every click not always 0.

```
def click(event):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    return clicks
print(clicks)
```

This case is simplified. Actually, my real case is that there are many different items(like listbox, button1, button2...) event hander function(def xxx(event)), and I need to get some value in each function after trigger their events. Then do some conditional expressions in global.

I knew the methods like class, global variable, **init**, (self, master),
I think global variable is the simplest method but I really don't know how to return it in event hander function and use it in global.

Thanks for Help !!!

Comment: The first piece of code looks correct. It prints 1, 2, 3, ... each time the button is pressed. What were you expecting?

Comment: if You place that print outside everything it will just go over it, execute and never return because it isn't called anymore

Comment: I want print(clicks) out of function  prints 1, 2, 3 by every click.
Even use global variable can't get the value outside the function?

Comment: @Alan Can you show us how you are trying to access `clicks`. Right now it is global and every time you click on the button it gets incremented by 1. You should be able to use it in other parts of your program as well.

Comment: @TheLizzard Though in the second part code, clicks always print 0, what I want is clicks prints 1, 2, 3... out of the  event hander function  by every click

Comment: @Alan Python executes your code only once unless it is in a function (excluding very very special circumstances). What is the problem with using the variable from inside that function?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it always prints 0 is that the program resets everything every after you close the tk window. If you want to save the values even after you close the window, maybe save it in the csv file or put it in the database. Does this help? or am I too far from what you're trying to say?

Comment: It will be much easier to use a `.txt` instead of a `.csv`

Comment: Yes that will do too

Comment: What I mean is the second case, every clicks always prints 0,
tk window is still there

Answer (score 0):

Your first set of code should work with the global variable like what TheLizzard said. Like what Matiiss said, if you place the print outside the function, it would be called once and never be called again.
As for what you are looking for, I'm assuming you want the button to be like a next button going through each item from the listbox and each time the next button hit one of the item in the listbox, it calls another function to obtain whatever that item has. Hopefully this code is what you are looking for or give you an idea.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lst = {'a':'a value', 'b':'b value', 'c':'c value'}
clicks = -1

def print_text(event):
    keys = list(lst.keys())
    print(lst[keys[lstbx.curselection()[0]]])

def click():
    global clicks
    lstbx.selection_clear(0, 'end')
    clicks = clicks + 1 if clicks < 2 else 0 # loop the list when reach end
    lstbx.selection_set(clicks)
    lstbx.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>') # force call function

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Next', command=click)
btn.pack()

lstbx = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='single')
lstbx.insert(0, *lst.keys())
lstbx.pack()
lstbx.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', print_text)

root.mainloop()
```